# How to mimic "scrolling text" on Auth0 homepage using TailwindCSS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, postcss

On the [Auth0 homepage](https://auth0.com), there are two pieces of scrolling text, the "everyone" and the "just anyone". After the page has fully loaded, those two texts change periodically.

[image: Auth0 homepage image]

I'm wondering, is there a way to mimic that using TailwindCSS v3, and React (Next.js)? I'm happy to install any external libraries if there are any that makes things easier.

I currently can't find any snippets on Google, and I tried to use the `transition` properties on Tailwind, but nothing I tried worked, either there's no animation or one was early or delayed. Same thing happened with the `animation` property.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @blurfus with the [`transition` property in tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property), but it didn't work. I also tried with the [animation property](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation), still, nothing there fits my needs for scrolling text.

Comment: Whatever you have tried, please add it to your question by [edit]ing it.